# Plotting the frequency of number of comments per day over time

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

In python, I have a data frame (`gme_interaction`) with three columns. One column is the time (`created`) when a post was commented. The second column is the number of comments the posts received (`num_comments`), and the third column in the actual comment.

I want a graph that plots the frequency of comments per day over time. How would you go about that?

Sample Data frame that like the actual one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["2021-01-01 00:02:06", "text", 4], ["2021-01-01 00:03:20", "[removed]", 6], ["2021-01-01 00:04:11", "text", 10]],
                    columns=['created', 'comment', 'num_comments'])
```

The `created` is however of `datetime64[ns]` type though. (Just not sure how to give it as such in the data frame).

So far I did that, but I’m not sure that it’s displaying what I really want.

```
gme_comments_per_day = gme_interaction.groupby(gme_interaction['created'])['num_comments'].sum()

### Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 12))
sns.barplot(x='created', y='num_comments', data=gme_comments_per_day)
plt.title('Title')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Total Number of Comments')

# Format x-axis labels
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())  # Set major ticks at days
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d'))  # Display day number

# Set minor ticks at 6-hour intervals (adjust for your specific intervals)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%I%p'))  # Display time intervals


#plt.xticks(rotation=50)  # Rotate x-axis labels for better readability
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('Evolution of Interaction in WSB during GME.pdf')
plt.show()
```

My plot looks like that, but I’m suspicious of the drop between 26th and 27th ish:
[image]

What I’m also suspicious about is the way the days are plotted, they fill a bit off.

Comment: can you provide an example dataframe? just make up one with a few example entries

Comment: What does your current plot look like? What time information is stored in `created`? Is it the date? Date and time? Something else?

Comment: @Leo edited the question thx

Comment: @jared edited the question thx

Comment: Judging by the sample df and the first line in your code block: `gme_comments_per_day = gme_interaction.groupby(gme_interaction['created'])['num_comments'].sum()` will give you the sum per unique time point, and not the day, so before grouping the data by time point, you need to transform the time column to only give the day, and not the exact time stamp.

Comment: What if I change it to that then: `gme_comments_per_day = gme_interaction.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created', freq='H'))['num_comments'].sum().reset_index()`

Comment: I don't quite understnad your suggestion but this does it: `gme_comments_per_day = df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.created).dt.day)['num_comments'].sum().reset_index()`